# Writing nested function in IF statement in R

Tags: r

I have a function of the following form:

```
a<-function(a,b,c){

if (a<0){ s<<-1;d<<-0; c
}
else { nest<-function(b,c){

if(b=0){ s<<-2; c}
else { 0
}
}
```

Is it possible to do it this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not particularly clear what you're trying to do.  If `a<0` then the two global assignments will take place and the function will return the value of `c`.  Otherwise (once you change `b=0` to `b==0` and add enough closing brackets) the function will *invisibly* return the function `nest` you defined.  It won't set `s` globally, because the function `nest` just gets defined, not called.

```
a<-function(a,b,c) {
   if (a<0){ 
      s<<-1;d<<-0; c
   } else { 
     nest<-function(b,c){
       if(b==0){ s<<-2; c} else { 0 }
     }
   }
}
```

First case:

```
a(-1,1,1)
## [1] 1
s
## [1] 1
d
## [1] 0
```

Second case:

```
x <- a(2,1,1)
x
## function(b,c){
##           if(b==0){ s<<-2; c} else { 0 }
##         }
## <environment: 0x998e634>
```

It seems more likely that you meant:

```
a <- function(a,b,c) {
   if (a<0){ 
      s<<-1;d<<-0; c
   } else { 
       if (b==0) { s<<-2; c} else { 0 }
   }
}
```

Which

- if `a<0` will set `s` and `d` globally and return `c`
- if `a>0` *and* `b==0` will set `s` globally and return `c`
- if `a>0` *and* `b!=0` will just return 0

By the way, it's a little confusing (although legal) to call your function `a` and to give it a parameter called `a`.

So the narrow answer to "can I do this?" is "yes, if you fix your syntax".  The broad answer is "I'm not sure what you're trying to do, what you're doing doesn't seem very sensible. If you can express the logic of what you're trying to do more clearly (i.e. what are the desired outcomes of different inputs?) then we can help you come up with code that embodies that logic."

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you try to do, but I assume that the function you would like to have does certain things depending on the values of the variables a, b, and c. You can do that with a function as the one below:

```
a <- function(a,b,c){
IF(a<0){
# do some stuff
}else{
# do some other stuff
} #close if statement
} #close function statement
```

In other words, there is no problem in using a if statement within a function.

Comment: No. What I'm asking is if its okay to execute a function within an IF statement that also has an IF statement. Look at my code it's there.

Comment: You are defining a function within your if-statement within a statement where the function gets defined. I don't really understand what the benefit from this would be. Generally, you use functions for something that is repetitive. Thus define functions for things you need to execute over and over again and then use normal code execute it. Executing a previous defined function within a function is no problem.

Answer (score 2):

It is ok to have nested `if` statments,

e.g.

```
myfun <- function(x){
                     if(x < 0){
 print("less") }else{
 if(x>7) {
 print("more") }else{
 print("middle")
         }
     }
 }

  myfun(-1)
[1] "less"
> myfun(8)
[1] "more"
 > myfun(6)
[1] "middle"
```

But in your second part you are saying `if` condition then name a function, not call the function. Obviously with choice I wouldn't use a function like the one above though, we can do better than that. Remember as well a useful tool to cut down on some of this is `ifelse`